# API response not visible while trying to map it in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I am trying to map an api response in to the DOM. There are two api endpoints being hit. The first is one that retrieves a list of queues, each queues with its own data. From the queue I extract the ID that belongs to that queue, and use it to hit another endpoint. The second API responds with a list of tickets waiting in the queue. I use a for loop to go through the first response and call the second api for each ID, and push each individual ticket in to a new array.

I am using Axios to make my get requests.

```
export var getFinalWaiting = () => {
    var result = []
    getQueues().then(res => {
        res.forEach(val => {
            getWaiting(val.id).then(res => {
                res.forEach(val1 => {
                    result.push(val1)
                })
            })
        })
    })
  
    return result
}
```

In my component, which is a table I then use useState and useEffect like so

```
let [waiting, setWaiting] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    var final = getFinalWaiting()
    setWaiting(final)
    
},[]);
```

I am then trying to map the data to three different h6 elements like so

```
<div id="vitalsTableColumns">
    <div className="vitalsTableColumn">
            <h5 className="vitalsTableHeading">Tickets</h5>
        {waiting.map(t  =>   
            <h5 className="vitalsTableContent"> 
                {t.ticketId }
            </h5>
        )}
    </div>
    <div className="vitalsTableColumn">
        <h5 className="vitalsTableHeading">Service</h5>
        {waiting ? waiting.map (t  => (
            <h6 className="vitalsTableContent">
                { t.currentVisitService.serviceInternalName }
            </h6>
        )) : ""}
    </div>
    <div className="vitalsTableColumn">
        <h5 className="vitalsTableHeading">Waiting Time</h5>
        {waiting ? waiting.map (t => (
            <h6 className="vitalsTableContent">
                { t.waitingTime }
            </h6>
        )) : ""}
    </div>
</div>
```

My list of tickets is 47 items long, each item containing around 40 subfields. I've attached an image of the generated list of tickets from devtools.

[Ticket list screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i0LM.png)

The issue is that there is no text being rendered to the DOM. I suspect that the response is too large, because the state of waiting is not being updated immediately when I log it. I'm assuming because the screen is rendering before the state is updated, and then not re-rendering,the data is not being rendered. Any ideas?

Comment: Is final just returning as an empty array or a filled one?

Comment: You do not wait on the async calls and just return the empty array that you set result to.

Comment: @AlphaWolfGamer when I log final or waiting, it logs multiple times. The first few times it logs as empty, but is then filled in the last two logs. all inside half a second

Comment: @Disco I'm not quite sure what you mean, could you please elaborate if its not too much trouble?

Comment: Posted a answer, not that since you have not shared all the code, the answer might not work and you will have to adjust it to fit you needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not shared all the dunction you use, I will have to assume some steps. As I said in the comment is the issue that you alway return an empty array from `getFinalWaiting` since you do not wait on the promises to resolve.

```js
export const getFinalWaiting = () => {
  // You set result here
  let result = [];
  // Assuming that getQueues and getWaiting are async functions since you use then.
  // This will create a promise, however, you are not returning it.
  getQueues().then((res) => {
    res.forEach((val) => {
      getWaiting(val.id).then((res) => {
        res.forEach((val1) => {
          result.push(val1);
        });
      });
    });
  });

  // The empty array will be returned here since you are not returning the promise
  return result;
};
```

Personally I think it get more readable to simply await the results rather than resolve alot of promises at once. You should change you code to something like the code below. However not that you can not plug and play this code since I do not have access to all your function.

```js
export const getFinalWaiting = async () => {
  let result = [];
  const queues = await getQueues();
  queues.forEach(async (val) => {
    const waiting = await getWaiting(val.id);
    waiting.forEach((val1) => {
      result.push(val1);
    });
  });
  return result;
};
```

In the useEffect you should not use awaits. But you could do something like this

```js
useEffect(() => {
    getFinalWaiting().then((final) => {
      setWaiting(final);
    });
  }, []);
```